# Grep arguments which contains at least a number

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep

How can I grep arguments which contains at least a number in a shell script ?

Example (**unlimited number of arguments !**) :

```
./test.sh Hello W0rld1
```

It should outputs :

```
W0rld1
```

For my script, I already did that :

```
searchErrorNumber=$(echo "${@}" | grep -o '[0-9]*')
```

With the same example, It outputs **just** the numbers :

```
ERROR : 0 1 is not valid.
```

It should outputs the word like that :

```
ERROR : W0rld1 is not valid.
```

Thanks for helping me !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In bash, you can use an array to keep the selected arguments. Use `[[ ... == ... ]]` with parameter matching to find the digits.

```sh
#! /bin/bash

contain_digit=()
for arg ; do
    shift
    if [[ "$arg" == *[0-9]* ]] ; then
        contain_digit+=("$arg")
    fi
done
printf '%s ' "${contain_digit[@]}"
echo
```

If you want to go the `grep` way, use `printf` to output each argument on a separate line (doesn't work for multiline arguments).

```
printf '%s\n' "$@" | grep '[0-9]'
```